# A list and its positions

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a code where you enter a sentence, it splits each word in the sentence to become a separate member. When I enter a word, and I enter it again, those two words will have the same word below. For instance,

```
This is a This is a 
 1   2  3  1    2 3
```

The problem is, that my code does this differently, for example,

```
This This Is Is 
 1     1   2  3
```

If it's done it twice, it will just continue to count forever.

Here is my code:

```
sent = input("Enter your sentence:").lower()
sentlist = sent.split()
print (sent)

for i in sentlist:
    if sentlist.index(i) in newlist:
        newlist.append(sentlist.index(i))
    else:
        newlist.append(int(count))
        count = count + 1
intlist = [x+1 for x in newlist]
print (intlist)
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: i'm afraid i can't get what you're asking. an example input and output would be good, or try to explain the problem a bit better.

Comment: I just ran your code¹ with the test input and got `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` – the desired result. ¹Well, with some additional lines because this is not a real good [mcve].

Comment: You can create a dictionary with these words and check if present increase count else add it to dictionary .

Comment: Use enumerate instead of index!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store each unique word and the position/index at which it was first seen in the input list. That dictionary can then be used to efficiently get the position/index of each word, which can then be appended to `newlist`:

```
sentlist = input("Enter your sentence:").lower().split()

newlist = []
position = 0
d = {}

for word in sentlist:
    if word not in d:
        position += 1
        d[word] = position
    newlist.append(d[word])

print(newlist)
```

**Output**

For input `This is a This is a`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

For `This This Is Is`:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

For `Hello this is a This is a bye`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For `Hello hello hello hello Hello`:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### Why your solution returns wrong results

When you're encounter a new word (in the else-case) you add a new number to your list, but this number isn't the index of the word, but the number of words already in the list.

The steps that will be executed in case of your second input ("This This Is Is")

1. `i == "this"` has index 0 and 0 is not in newlist so it appends 0 to the list and increments `count` to 1
2. `i == "this"` has also index 0 which is already in newlist, so it adds it another time
3. `i == "is"` has index **2** which is not in newlist, so it appends `count` to the newlist (which has the value **1**) and increments it
4. `i == "is"` has index **2** which is not in newlist, so it appends `count` to the newlist (which has the value **2**) and increments it

In order to solve this, either also use `sentlist.index()` instead of `count`.

### Better solution

In order to improve this use a dictionary instead  of lists. This allows you to effienctly store the positions of encountered words and build the result.

Example:

```
sentence = input("Enter your sentence:").lower()
words = sentence.split()

positions = {}   # positions for each word
count = 0        # number of unique words
poslist = []     # the positions for the given sentence

for word in words:
    if word in positions:
        pos = positions[word] # get the position of word from the dictionary
        poslist.append(pos)
    else:
        # new word encountered
        count += 1
        positions[word] = count # store the position for word in the dictionary
        poslist.append(count)

print(poslist)
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation.